# recover original YUY2 buffer from BMP

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a camera that gives me a stream of YUYV data. It is actually a stereo camera and Y is encoding one sensor and U and V the other one. I'm using OpenCV to get this data and saved it into a bmp file using this simplistic script:

```
import cv2
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # index of camera

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

i=0
folder=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame2 = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame2)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

    if c == 13:
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder,("%04d" % (i,))+".bmp"), frame)
        i=i+1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I thought in BMP saving the raw buffer values would be saved but I can't recover the images. I tried loading the bmp as `img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` and display its first channel and also reading it as `img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` and converting it back to YUV but there is always artifacts of the other image in the channels. Can you give me a hint how to get the original YUYV buffer representation?

Comment: By default OpenCV `ret, frame = cap.read()` converts the frame to BGR format. OpenCV conversion assumes that the data format is YUYV, and mixes the channels. `frame2 = cv2.resize` makes things worse, because it loses more data when downscaling. Try calling `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)` for preventing the conversion to BGR (I am not sure that it's going to work). What is `frame.shape` before and after using `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)`?

Comment: you should turn the comment into an answer

Comment: I appreciate the comment as it is helpful when trying to modify the script to write the original buffers. Anyway, if I would write that again I would do the decoupling of the left/right image from the buffer before and save the images into two files. But my question was about getting the original data back as already quite some images have been taken in a scenario that I can not recreate easily.

Comment: feel free to post the data you have. when in doubt about the compulsive conversion of image hosters, just upload to a file hoster.

Answer (score -1):

To correctly save and recover the original YUYV buffer, you need to handle the conversion from YUYV to RGB or YUV before saving and after reading the image.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # index of camera

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

i = 0
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert YUYV to RGB
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUYV)

    frame2 = cv2.resize(frame_rgb, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow('Input', frame2)

    c = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if c == 27:
        break

    if c == 13:
        # Save as BMP
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(folder, ("%04d" % i) + ".bmp"), frame_rgb)
        i = i + 1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I'm aware of what I have to do to the script (actually I would record with cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1) to get raw pixel values and separate left and right image already before saving). The problem is that a series of images has already been taken. So I'm looking specifically for a reversal of the YUYV -> BGR (or RGB) that the OpenCV backend has done. This would enable me to still use the recorded images.

Comment: @Cookie if this is the case, note that it's not possible to recover the original frames. BGR -> YUYV may get you close (not perfect) if you haven't used `cv2.resize`. Using `cv2.resize` makes it impossible to recover.

Comment: I'm aware of that. You can see in the script, that frame_rgb is resized for displaying into frame2 but the original frame_rgb is written. So output bmps are full resolution.